# AspNetBoilerplate - HttpContext is null in custom TenantResolveContributor

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

#### Documentation

I've read the documentation at https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy

I added a custom TenantResolveContributor to the application project and added it to the collection in WebModule.PreInitialize.

```
        Configuration.MultiTenancy.Resolvers.Add<NameTenantResolveContributor>();
```

In WebModule.Initialize, I resolve my TenantAppService so it can be injected into RouteConfig.

```
        TenantAppService tenantAppService = IocManager.Resolve<TenantAppService>();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes, tenantAppService);
```

When execution reaches RouteConfig, it correctly goes into NameTenantResolveContributor, but the HttpContext is null.

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.

- Abp package version : 6.0.0
- Base framework: .Net

> Request is not available in this context
> at System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request()
> at DemoApp.MultiTenancy.NameTenantResolveContributor.ResolveTenantId() in >D:\src\ABP\DemoProject\6.0.0\src\DemoProject.Application\MultiTenancy\NameTenantResolveContributor.cs:line 40
> at Abp.MultiTenancy.TenantResolver.GetTenantIdFromContributors()

The stack trace is oddly brief and undescriptive. When I copy the details, the message is

```html
System.Web.HttpException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Request is not available in this context
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

[image: StackTrace]

```html
using Abp.Configuration.Startup;
using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Abp.Extensions;
using Abp.MultiTenancy;
using Abp.Text;
using Abp.Web.MultiTenancy;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace DemoApp.MultiTenancy
{
    public class NameTenantResolveContributor : ITenantResolveContributor, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly IMultiTenancyConfig _multiTenancyConfig;
        private readonly ITenantStore _tenantStore;

        public NameTenantResolveContributor(IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancyConfig, ITenantStore tenantStore)
        {
            _multiTenancyConfig = multiTenancyConfig;
            _tenantStore = tenantStore;
        }

        public int? ResolveTenantId()
        {
            string tenancyName = "";

            string[] urlParts = null;

            var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            //This is where the error occurs
            urlParts = httpContext.Request.Url.Segments.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('/')).Skip(1).ToArray();
            tenancyName = urlParts[0].ToLower();

            var tenantInfo = _tenantStore.Find(tenancyName);
            if (tenantInfo == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return tenantInfo.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: I've updated my post with a few details explaining that the stack trace is odd.